# XAML: ContentPresenter for an OpacityMask

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I'm making a custom controlTemplate for toggleButtons that changes the color of a specified image based on the toggle state. My plan was to use a rectangle with a color based on the visualState and use the image for its opacityMask. The design time error I get back is that ContentPresenter is that it expects a brush.

Is it not valid to have a contentPresenter provide that brush? Isn't the whole point of a contentPresenter to provide the content of the control using the style?

Here is a simplified version of my code for reference:

```
<Style x:Key="customToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ContentPresenter does not provide anything.
It is a control, like any other control, it inherits from FrameworkElement / UIElement.

The "OpacityMask" property, expects a brush (like your error is stating). A Brush is inheriting from DependencyObject.

So long story short, no you can't do that.

Please try to explain more accurately what you are tying to accomplish. Are you just trying to modify the opacity of the content of your control ?